# Material Components Web and React: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined;

Tags: reactjs, material-components

I am trying to build a Modal component taking advantage of React and Material Components Web. The visibility of Modal is inherited from the parent state as props:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {MDCFormField} from '@material/form-field/';
import {MDCTextfield} from '@material/textfield/';
import './modal.scss';

export default class Modal extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
  this.email = new MDCTextfield(this.email);
  this.pwd = new MDCTextfield(this.pwd);
}

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.email.destroy();
    this.pwd.destroy();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.isModalOpen){
      return (
        <div id="modal-container">
          <div id="mask"></div>
          <div id="modal">
            <form className="mdc-form-field">

              <div ref={(div) => {this.email = div}} className="mdc-textfield">
                <label type="email" htmlFor="email" className="mdc-textfield__label">Your email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" className="mdc-textfield__input"/>
                <div className="mdc-textfield__bottom-line"></div>
              </div>

              <div ref={(div) => {this.pwd = div}} className="mdc-textfield">
                <label htmlFor="pw" className="mdc-textfield__label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="pw" className="mdc-textfield__input" required minLength={8}/>
                <div className="mdc-textfield__bottom-line"></div>
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }
}
```

As soon as the app initialise an error appears "TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined”

Of course it does since the since as the Modal is returning null.

so i tried to initialise Material Components as

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.email = this.email && new MDCTextfield(this.email);
    this.pwd = this.pwd && new MDCTextfield(this.pwd);
  }
```

In this case the error is not thrown anymore but obviously the components are not initialised.

I did not come up with a pattern to solve this problem. Also a css approach did not work ( the idea was to toggle .someClass {display: none} from the main container ).

/** SOLVED **/

Ok I came up with a working pattern to solve the problem.
The problem was in the architecture of the app and the encapsulation of the components was not appropriate.

This is a parent component called Modal:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import EmailField from './email-field';
import PwdField from './password-field';
import './modal.scss';

export default class Modal extends Component {

  render() {
    if (this.props.isModalOpen){
      return (
        <div id="modal-container">
          <div id="mask"></div>
          <div id="modal">
              <form className="mdc-form-field">
                <EmailField />
                <PwdField />
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }
}
```

Than we have Children components as

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {MDCTextfield} from '@material/textfield/';

export default class EmailField extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.email = new MDCTextfield(this.email);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.email.destroy();
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div ref={(div) => {this.email = div}} className="mdc-textfield">
          <label type="email" htmlFor="email" className="mdc-textfield__label">Your email</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" className="mdc-textfield__input"/>
          <div className="mdc-textfield__bottom-line"></div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I was trying to init and destroy from a different scope of MDCTextfield elements.

Comment: Can you share which material library you are using ?

Comment: A straight forward "yarn add material-components-web"

Comment: This will help you https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web

Comment: You will also have to insert some scripts identified here in your index.html. Refer to the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out the [react version](https://react-mdc.github.io/#/) of this library.

Comment: Thanks Fawaz but i got this error "Class constructor MDCTextfield cannot be invoked without 'new'".If I hard edit parent state (isModalOpen = true) everything works as expected.

Comment: @TheBluerock I think you should try something more tested to work properly with React. Maybe my updated answer will help you better!

Answer (score 0):

Try to console.log(this.email). Afterwards you will see, that ref that you try to pass is not a selector, this is expected when you initialise matertial-components.
*@Fawaz* answer is correct, but you can instantiate it the way you want, even on `div`.

Showcase: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KwEsyJR3O3eW50gX2pq

Did you using components like i am using there?

Use this for reference: 
[Material Components Textfield, Manual Instantiation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-textfield#manual-instantiation)

Comment: console.log(this.email) outputs MDCTextfield object  with all the properties described in his foundation.

Comment: Then you can use this object, or use react version, as stated _@Fawaz_